# Syntax error in SQL statement org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

Hi this is my repository

```
@Repository
interface GuestRepository : JpaRepository<Guest, Long> {

@Query("from Guests g where g.date>=:fromDate and g.date<=:toDate ",nativeQuery = true)
fun findInPeriod(
        @Param("fromDate") fromDate: Date
        , @Param("toDate") toDate: Date
        , pageRequest: Pageable
): Page<Guest>

}
```

and this is my guest object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Guests")
data class Guest(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "guest_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "guest_seq", sequenceName = "guest_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    val id: Long=0
    ,
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    val userName: String="username"
    , val firstName: String?=null
    , val lastName: String?=null
    ,
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    val date: Date=Date()
)
```

I use spring and h2 but when I run my application it show me this error message

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "FROM GUESTS G WHERE[*] G.DATE>=? AND G.DATE<=?  LIMIT ? "; expected "(, USE, RIGHT, LEFT, FULL, INNER, JOIN, CROSS, NATURAL, ,, SELECT"; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `nativeQuery = true` you tell Spring Data JDBC to treat your query as a native, i.e a SQL, query.

But the query you provide is not legal SQL. 
It looks very much like HQL which is a Hibernate specific dialect of JPQL.

To fix the problem remove the `nativeQuery = true` part or use SQL